Docker Python Django socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
I'm currently working on a project built with Django hosted on Togglebox, with multiple docker containers being routed through nginx.
I'm currently getting this error when I try to deploy it up:
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
Here's the full run log:
162 static files copied to '/nfs/static', 3 unmodified.
[2024-05-09 21:44:58 +0000] [5924] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2024-05-09 21:44:58 +0000] [5924] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8115 (5924)
[2024-05-09 21:44:58 +0000] [5924] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-05-09 21:44:58 +0000] [5996] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5996
Could not connect to host.docker.internal: 5115
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 463, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
[2024-05-09 21:44:59 +0000] [5996] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/code/adentify/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    pydevd_pycharm.settrace(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 1706, in settrace
    _locked_settrace(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 1762, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 660, in connect
    s = start_client(host, port)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 463, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
[2024-05-09 21:44:59 +0000] [5996] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5996)
[2024-05-09 21:44:59 +0000] [5924] [ERROR] Worker (pid:5996) exited with code 3
[2024-05-09 21:44:59 +0000] [5924] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
[2024-05-09 21:44:59 +0000] [5924] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Now, as for the line
Could not connect to host.docker.internal: 5115
I am aware that we have a port open for connecting a debugging thread to our container(s), and I believe that that is that port. However, it's not supposed to be a fatal error if it fails to connect there. In fact, I am able to locally build and run the images from a different branch of our git repository, and the stack trace will have this line, but it will not cause a fatal crash.
I suspect that the issue lies in our configuration somewhere, but I'm not sure where to start looking for the root of the issue.
Usually, I can build the image locally, deploy it to togglebox, redeploy the container, and have it boot up as it does in my local instance on a different branch. However, following those same steps, the run log displays that stack trace and fails to boot.
